# Apache Camel in Springboot Admin Server?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I have multiple springboot services which runs various Apache Camel polls and i was wondering if the springboot admin server could be used to get some kind of overview of the schedules/poll or perhaps if there is some other tool which can gather these informations from various SpringBoot/Camel services ?

Comment: What kind of Camel polls, can you tell more what they are

Comment: Sofar its plain sftp and aws-s3 that are setup to look for files at a regular frequency. It would be nice to be able to get info like how often they are set to poll, latest successfull poll, latest successfull poll with an exchange and stats like that

Comment: Camel has a lot of information you can see via camel-management (JMX) and that information can also be exposed for other metric systems.

Comment: There is a web ui, hawtio that can show such information also. And the Camel CLI (camel-jbang) as well.

Comment: Thanks - i will try to start with the hawtio. Cant figure out how to mark the answer as accepted, but both is good

Comment: This could be something that i was looking for https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin
I will check this out